# Use negative x or y values in Plotly surface data?

Tags: javascript, plot, plotly

Plotly surface data is arranged as a 2d Array (a matrix) whose indices correspond to x and y values and whose elements indicate the z values.  E.g. if element [0][0] equals 10, that indicates an (x,y,z) coordinate of (0,0,10).

**The problem: Because Array indices start at zero, it seems impossible to graph surfaces that have negative x or y values.**

[Here is a CodePen](https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/GogNjj) with three surfaces plotted.  The surfaces look fine because only two octants are shown in the graph - the `(+x,+y)` quadrant.  If all octants are displayed in the graph ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/sensei/pen/rGRPjd)), then it ends up looking incomplete because the plotted surfaces won't extend into the remaining 3 quadrants.

The general form of surface data is:

```
{ z       : dataArray,
  type    : 'surface',
  opacity : 0.9 }
```

Is there a way to give the surface data an xstart or ystart, or the like, so that full 3d surfaces can be drawn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your own `x` and `y` coordinates, Plotly just *assumes* them if you do not provide them.

From the [documentation](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#surface-x):

> `x` (data array)
>   Sets the x coordinates.
>
> `y` (data array)
>   Sets the y coordinates.

Code is based on the example [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/3d-surface-plots/#multiple-3d-surface-plots).

```js
z = [[8.83,8.89,8.81,8.87,8.9,8.87],
     [8.89,8.94,8.85,8.94,8.96,8.92],
     [8.84,8.9,8.82,8.92,8.93,8.91],
     [8.79,8.85,8.79,8.9,8.94,8.92],
     [8.79,8.88,8.81,8.9,8.95,8.92],
     [8.8,8.82,8.78,8.91,8.94,8.92],
     [8.75,8.78,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.92],
     [8.8,8.8,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.94],
     [8.74,8.81,8.76,8.93,8.98,8.99],
     [8.89,8.99,8.92,9.1,9.13,9.11],
     [8.97,8.97,8.91,9.09,9.11,9.11],
     [9.04,9.08,9.05,9.25,9.28,9.27],
     [9,9.01,9,9.2,9.23,9.2],
     [8.99,8.99,8.98,9.18,9.2,9.19],
     [8.93,8.97,8.97,9.18,9.2,9.18]];

var x = [];
var y = [];
for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i += 1) {
  x[i] = [];
  y[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < z[i].length; j += 1) {
    x[i].push(j + i - 10);
    y[i].push(j - 3);
  }
}

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [{z: z, 
                         x: x, 
                          y: y, 
                          type: 'surface'}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```